# How to refactor an android library module to kotlin module in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-module, modularization

I have removed the android library dependencies to some of the modules in my app and would like to convert these modules to pure 'java or kotlin' modules.

What is the best way to do this in Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I found is to update the `plugins` block in the build.gradle file. Remove `'com.android.library'` and add `'java-library'` and `'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm'`.